# Windows 10 UWP - How do I query an ink device's sampling rate?

Tags: uwp, touch, windows-10-universal, pen

As in the title, how might I query a device that is producing ink input about the rate at which it produces new stroke points? For instance, how can I tell that the pen I am using is sampling at 120 Hz or 60 Hz?

I know that [InkPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpoint) themselves have a [Timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkpoint.timestamp) property that theoretically provides this information, but in our experience and from data we've gathered, it's incredibly noisy and not useful for our purposes. We're finding better results by simply assuming that the system is providing a particular sampling rate most of the time, but we would want our app to determine what that sampling rate actually is instead of guessing a potentially inaccurate number.

Comment: Why do you want to get ink device's sampling rate?

Comment: The timing data on the InkPoints themselves is extremely noisy, with a lot of variance between points. I want a value that represents an average of what that timing data should be.

Comment: Have you tied to sue Device Watcher Class to get device info ?

Comment: Device Watcher has the sort of information you would find in the Device Manager program in System Tools. None of those properties indicate the sample rate of the input device.

Comment: I have researched some info about ink device, unfortunately, there is no such description about  sample rate. If you do want this feature please feel free to ask in the [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent).